# Пунктуация (тире) в СПП

Tags: пунктуация, спп, тире

*"С чего вдруг решила о таком подумать ( ) сама не знаю".*

У меня дикое желание на месте пропуска поставить тире, но сомневаюсь, что здесь оно вообще нужно.

Answer (score 3):

Тире ставится:

**С чего вдруг решила о таком подумать —  сама не знаю.**

Но это не БСП (бессоюзное сложное предложение), а СПП (сложноподчиненное предложение, в качестве связи используется союзное слово С ЧЕГО.

Тире ставится **для интонационного отделения главной части сложноподчиненного предложения от придаточной.** Чаще всего тире употребляется в тех случаях, когда главной части предшествует:
1) **придаточная изъяснительная:** Как он добрался сюда — уж этого никак не мог он понять (Г.); Как рассказывал учитель — долго слушал у окна я (Пл.);

http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=142#pp142